# Converting response data from API into table in Power BI using Python

Tags: python, json, api, powerbi

I use python script to connect to an API. The response received is below. I need to convert this data into a multi-level table to be imported into PowerBI as it has a few levels of data (for example, "rooms" is further split and creates a problem)

The response from the API is as below:

```
{"data": {"code": "AZ-0001", "date_from": "23/12/2019", "date_to": "25/12/2019", "rsrv_date": "06/12/2019", "rooms": [{"rrid": 4057782, "room_name": "STD", "date_from.......
```

Then convert this using Python Dataframe. This is my python script to get the data from the API

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
import json

uspw=('<API KEY>', None)
data= {'rcode': 'AZ-0001'}
response= requests.post('https://kapi.wubook.net/kapi/rsrvs/reservation', data, auth= uspw)

data = response.text
print(data)
#df = pd.read_json(data, orient='split')

from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
jdata = json.loads(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(jdata)


#dg = json_normalize(data)
print (df)
```

The output received in powerBi table looks like this:
[image]

As you can see, the column rooms data is not split. How can I split this into separate columns as well? Thanks alot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to save that json to a file, and then import as a new query (Get Data>Json). 
Another way is to add these steps to your query, in Advanced Editor:

```
    jsonParser = Json.Document(#"PreviousStep"[json]{0}),
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(jsonParser , Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error)
in
    #"Converted to Table"
```

Make sure to replace #"PreviousStep" by the name of yout previous step.